# Alternative for a linked list in CUDA

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, linked-list, cuda, save

I have a problem with my CUDA code. I search for values in an 1D array. When I found for example the value 255 in an RGB image i want to store the index of this value without gaps.

I know how to do it with standard c++ (like a linked list) but i have no clue how to do this in parallel with cuda c.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

One possible approach, using atomics:

```
const int MAX_SIZE = MAX_SIZE_OF_IMAGE;
const int nTPB = 256;
__device__ int base = 0;
__device__ int dev_indices[MAX_SIZE];
template <typename T>
__global__ void findvalindex(const T* __restrict__ imagedata, const T val, const int imagelen){
  int idx=threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < imagelen)
    if (imagedata[idx] == val){
      int mylocation = atomicAdd(&base, 1);
      dev_indices[mylocation] = idx;}
  }
```

in host code:

```
// assume image data is already copied to the device using device pointer image
findvalindex<<<(MAX_SIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB, nTPB>>>(image, 255, MAX_SIZE);
int num_indices;
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&num_indices, base, sizeof(int));
int *indices = new int[num_indices];
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(indices, dev_indices, sizeof(int)*num_indices));
// indices now contains the list of matching indices
```

(coded in browser)

The basic idea here is that we are using atomics to guarantee that every thread that finds a match will get a unique insertion point in the index array.  There will be no gaps using this method.